# Solve maze with python, speed issue

Tags: python, performance

I'm currently trying to speeding up my python code.
The code should calculate all the possible routes in a maze that is generated from a black and white image. The maze should be solved starting from the 0,j pixel of the image to every point in the bottom of the image(Better explained in the image attached).[image]

At the moment my code takes 3 min for analyze 240x120 pixel image. I would like to analyze an image that is 16000 x 1000, do you think is possible?

I have tryed to cythonize my code but I didn't sucseed in it, so I was trying to solv my problem within python.

Tell me if you have any idea to speed up my code. Thank you in advance!

This is an example of Interpred picture (only with 0 and 1) and output results (with incremental number from 1) where an extra step is added wherever there is a 0 in the matrix (0 represents passage, 1 is wall)[image]

[image]

```py
from matplotlib.image import imread

import numpy as np
from time import time




start_time = time()

image= imread("white_fibers2.jpg") 

array_of_tuples = map(tuple, image)
image2 = tuple(array_of_tuples)

threshold= 170




image1 = np.zeros((len(image2),len(image2[0])))



for i in range(len(image2)):
    for j in range(len(image2[i])):
        
        if image2[i][j] >threshold:
            
            image1[i][j]=0
        else:
            image1[i][j]=1  ### matrix AKA wall in the labyrinth 
         
f = np.zeros(len(image2[1]))

##### from array image 1 to tuple image 3
# array_of_tuples1 = map(tuple, image1)
# image3 = tuple(array_of_tuples1)

image3=np.array(image1)

for w in range(len(image3[1])-1):
    
    if image1[0,w]==0:

        start = 0, w
        end = len(image2)-1, 0
        
        
        ##### empty matrix that will store the possible moves
        
        
        m = []
        for i in range(len(image3)):
            m.append([])
            for j in range(len(image3[i])):
                m[-1].append(0)
                
              
        i,j = start
        m[i][j] = 1
    
        
        def make_step(k,m,image3):
         
          for i in range(len(m)):
             
            for j in range(len(m[i])):
              if m[i][j] == k:
                 
                if i>0 and m[i-1][j] == 0 and image3[i-1][j] == 0:   ##### if there is space in Maze (no space no way) and there is space in the path (to avoid that goes back)
                  m[i-1][j] = k + 1   ####### on top of the square i,j
                  
                   
                if j>0 and m[i][j-1] == 0 and image3[i][j-1] == 0:
                  m[i][j-1] = k + 1   ####### on left of the square i,j 
                  
                 
                if i<len(m)-1 and m[i+1][j] == 0 and image3[i+1][j] == 0:
                  m[i+1][j] = k + 1   ####### on bottom of the square i,j
                  
                 
                if j<len(m[i])-1 and m[i][j+1] == 0 and image3[i][j+1] == 0:
                  m[i][j+1] = k + 1   ####### on right of the square i,j
        
                
       
                       
                  
                      
        ####### continue to perform step till the end point is reached + if there is a cul-de-sac it 
        k = 0
        
        
        while m[end[0]][end[1]] == 0 :
            
            if k<600:
                
                k += 1
                
                
                make_step(k,m, image3)
            
                # make_step(k,m, image3)
                  
                print (k)
            else:
                
              break
          
        path=np.array(m)
        
    
        f = np.vstack((f,path[end[0]])) ###### f contain the final line of the final line of the paths
    
    else:    ######## if the starting block of the maze is a wall fill the row of "f" with zeros
              
        p = np.zeros(len(image2[1]))
        f = np.vstack((f,p))
  
    
########

f1=np.delete(f,np.where(~f.any(axis=1))[0], axis=0) ##### remove the row with only 0s
    

ns =[]

   
for i in range(len(f1)):
    
    
    a= f1[i,:]
   
    ns.append(np.min(a[np.nonzero(a)]))

rz=0            
for i in range(len(ns)): 
    rz= rz+ 1/(ns[i])
    
    Rzi = 1/rz   

end_time = time()
print (end_time - start_time)
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example matrix (interpreted picture) and your validated output for that matrix?

Comment: Also please try to plot the actual output of the code, instead of drawing the path by hand!

Comment: 16,000 x 1000 should be an easy task, if approached correctly. The problem is not that you don't micro-optimize enough, the problem lies in your principle algorithm. It looks like you have a four times nested loop, when you should use something like breadth first search to solve the problem in linear theim.

Comment: Thanks Andreas T, the bredth first search seems like a promising technique to use. However I have a starting point for my maze but not an single end point (i Want to find the shorter route to reach the other end of the maze, so, all the points in the last row are possible ending points), therefore I don t know how to backroute in order to find the shorthest path.

Comment: As already noted, you need a better algorithm, not minor tweaks. Here's an explanation for the [A* algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097677/55857). It's a variation on BFS designed to visit all nodes and find shortest path. In your case, the weights are all 1. Regarding multiple endpoints, after creating the graph from the image, you can attach an extra pseudo-node to the graph that connects to all nodes/pixels in the last row (and only to those nodes). Treat that extra node as the goal for A*.

Comment: I second FMc. A* would be one of the better algorithms to use in this scenario. If you would like sample code for how to implement it in Python, [this page](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) has the best explanation I've seen yet